# What are the ways in jBPM to show Image in Process task Form

Tags: java, jboss, jbpm

I am having a use case where I need to show an Image in Process task Form. Which I have marked as "Image Area" in the first image. In the Second image can we have image data type?

**Image 1**
[image: Image 1]

**Image 2**
[image: Image 2]